# Unable to synchronize contacts to and from Salesforce to Sitecore using the official connector Salesforce Connect 2.x

Tags: sitecore

I have set up Sitecore 9 and have installed the Salesforce Connect 2.x module.

The documentation for this version seems to be not available and hence I am following the one released for 1.4 version.

For syncing the contact, I need to run the Pipeline batch job "Salesforce Contacts Sync Pipeline Batch". The job has executed with no errors. But still I am not able to view the contacts imported in the Experience Profile. I tried to connect to xConnect via the API's and have got no contacts from Salesforce as well.

Could I get any pointers on how to do bi-directional sync between Salesforce and Sitecore 9

Comment: I don't quite understand why there was a -1 on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases I've found that Salesforce Connect is working correctly and that the problem is an incorrect understanding of Experience Profile.

A contact must have an interaction assigned to it in order to appear in Experience Profile. If you just synchronize contacts, those contacts will not have any interactions, and therefore will not appear in Experience profile.

The product includes a pipeline batch to bring completed Salesforce tasks into Sitecore as interactions. But if you don't run that sync process, or if your contacts do not have any completed tasks in Salesforce, no interactions will be created for the contacts, and again, none of the contacts will appear in Experience Profile.

A better test to determine whether the sync process is working is to start with the log, which will tell you if any errors occured, and whether or not any data was submitted to xConnect.

After you have established that data is being submitted to xConnect, then you can use the xConnect API to determine which contacts were brought in from Salesforce. The product documentation for xConnect offers many of examples of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I have run both the piplelines, for syncing contacts and tasks from Salesforce to Sitecore. I have created completed tasks for the contacts, but it seems that the contacts are not synced.
I have checked the table "Contacts" in both Shard 0 and Shard 1 Databases. I have used the xConnect API and there are no results from there as well. In Experience Profile, I cannot see any contacts (after adding the completed tasks as you have mentioned). I can see only the contact that I have manually added using the xConnect API's (added a contact and an interaction)

Comment: Another issue is that the logs for the Data Exchange Framework is not being displayed. I am getting an "Object reference not set to object" error when I am trying to view the log files from the pipeline batches items. Is there a configuration that I should be enabling for viewing the logs?

Comment: Hard to tell what is causing the null object error, but that functionality is just a shortcut to viewing the log files. You can always go directly to where the logs are and find the file.

Comment: I have found that the Logs specific to my Salesforce tenant App_Data\Logs\Data Exchange\{Tenant Name} is not getting created. But in the logs in the Data Exchange folder I can see only the below message: "A critical error occurred while running the pipeline batch. " & " Pipeline batch was aborted." Could you suggest how can I proceed with further investigations

Comment: Is there anything in Salesforce (apart from creating the App and the token, as given in the installation guide) that i need to follow. There are no specific configurations in the website root and all dlls seems to be intact. The endpoint connections are established with no errors. How can i programatically run the pipeline batches. In the v1.4.1 we could use the below code  var runner = new InProcessPipelineBatchRunner();
                    if (runner.Run(pipelineBatch)). But now the runner.Run is expecting a PiplineBatchContext as well. How can i set this Context? Any pointers would help

Comment: First of all I would change the log level on the pipeline batch to include DEBUG. This will give you detailed logging that will help pinpoint the problem. As far as running a pipeline batch via code, you must create a new PipelineBatchContext item. Just use the constructor. Be aware, however, that if you run the pipeline batch this way, you are responsible for providing an ILogger instance. If you don't provide one, you will see no logging.